# Windows 10 PRO VGA HDMI BUG Second screen doesn't work

Tags: windows, hdmi, vga, asus-laptop, black-screen-of-death

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I really need help. I needed some emulators for my school project so I upgraded my Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 PRO. This was without any problems a success, emulators are working fine with Hyper-V.

But yesterday I saw that my second screen is black. I am connecting it to my laptop (Asus N550JV) with VGA, normally it work but now it doesn't anymore. Also my project partner same problems we did it together.

I need to presentate my project over a week so I need to connect it with the school beamer. Please help me out, if I downgrade to Home again I cannot use the emulator. But if I don't downgrade I can't use the VGA or HDMI.

What I tried: - Windows updates - Device manager updated screen adapters - Installed VGA driver from the Asus website (worked for 5 minutes fine after that switched to black screen again).

Thanks for your time hope you guys know a solution called Microsoft and Asus too but didnt get even closer.

Windows shows 6 monitors are connected with my laptop, but It isn't. This happened after the installation of Hyper-V!
Look:
[Monitor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqRFH.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You should post your resolution as an answer. Self-answered questions are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Hyper-V was enabled in : [This location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlI58.png) disable it and done. All the other 6 screens are gone now. Hope this will help other that may occur to this problem too.